# I want create a list from values in a dataset based on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, if-statement

I am working with a Dataset that contains the information of every March Madness game since 1985. I want to know which teams have won it all and how many times each.

I masked the main dataset and created a new one containing only information about the championship game. Now I am trying to create a loop that compares the scores from both teams that played in the championship game, detects the winner and adds that team to a list. This is how the dataset looks like: https://imgur.com/tXhPYSm

```
tourney = pd.read_csv('ncaa.csv')

champions = tourney.loc[tourney['Region Name'] == "Championship", ['Year','Seed','Score','Team','Team.1','Score.1','Seed.1']]

list_champs = []

for i in champions:
    if champions['Score'] > champions['Score.1']:
        list_champs.append(i['Team'])
    else:
        list_champs.append(i['Team.1'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to loop through the `DataFrame`?

Basic filtering should work well. Something like this:

```
champs1 = champions.loc[champions['Score'] > champions['Score.1'], 'Team']
champs2 = champions.loc[champions['Score'] < champions['Score.1'], 'Team.1']

list_champs = list(champs1) + list(champs2)
```

Comment: Thank you. my little experience made me think looping was the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

A minimalist change (not the most efficient) to get your code working:

```
tourney = pd.read_csv('ncaa.csv')

champions = tourney.loc[tourney['Region Name'] == "Championship", ['Year','Seed','Score','Team','Team.1','Score.1','Seed.1']]

list_champs = []

for row in champions.iterrows():
    if row['Score'] > row['Score.1']:
        list_champs.append(row['Team'])
    else:
        list_champs.append(row['Team.1'])
```

Otherwise, you could simply do:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row['Team'] if row['Score'] > row['Score.1'] else row['Team.1'], axis=1).values
```